# How do i prevent a nested for loop from duplicating answers in java

Tags: java, arrays

I had to create an array and take the values of that array to determine which numbers inside the array were spaced two numbers apart. I figured that part out but my output is duplicating and I need it to not do that. How do I keep it from duplicating answers.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[y];
        for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
            values[j] = scan.nextInt();     

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++){
            for(int k = 0; k < values.length; k++){
                if(values[i] == (values[k]-x))
                    System.out.print(values[k] + "," +  values[i] + " -- ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is hidden by your indentation.  You need to terminate the first for loop (with the `j` loop variable) before you start the second (with the `i` loop variable).

Comment: This question is a walking advertisement for _always_ using `{` and `}`.  Every time you have a branch, a loop or a `try` block, begin and end its content with `{` and `}` respectively, or _this_ kind of thing will happen.

Comment: @DavidWallace Agree to both of your points

Comment: Sorry, @ScaryWombat, I should have worded that far more tactfully.

Comment: Thank you! @DavidWallace I didn't even realize that I had misplaced my brackets

Comment: Emily, every Java / C / C++ / C# programmer has done exactly this, at some point in his or her career.  It's an easy thing to miss.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is hidden by your indentation.  You need to terminate the initializing for loop before you start the second one.  I also removed some redundant comparisons by modifying the 3rd for loop a little, but you might not need that change for the program to work.  As an aside, I highly recommend the use of an IDE which automatically indents your code as you write it.  It will catch these sorts of errors, because it will indent your code in an unexpected way if you make a mistake with braces:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Separation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Random r = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter k");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of values:");
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[y];
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            values[j] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (int k = i+0; k < values.length; k++) {

                if (Math.abs((values[i] - values[k]))==x)
                    System.out.print(values[k] + "," + values[i] + " -- ");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for the sequences, I've been trying, I get identical output for both versions of the code.  Is there an input sequence I can try that would reproduce the problem you encountered?

Comment: `x` being the difference between the numbers that is being searched for?  I thought  that was a constant entered by the user.  Its value never changes after it is entered by the user, so I'm not sure what you mean by it _increasing_ versus _decreasing_.

Comment: I would start at `k=i+1` and add another `if` like this: `if (values[k] == (values[i] - x))
                    System.out.print(values[i] + "," + values[k] + " -- ");`
 This way you wont miss backwards nor forwards..

Comment: I don't think using `Math.abs` is right because the print statement would be different, you will be switching `values[i]` with `value[k]` in the output..

Comment: I realized my mistake.  I've changed the `if` statement so that it uses absolute values to calculate the difference between the values of the two indexes.  This removes some of the duplicate checks that I believe the original algorithms made.

Comment: @Everyone: I don't think the order matters, because the original task is to find which numbers "are spaced 2 numbers apart."

Comment: @DavidChoweller If the order doesn't matter then yeah, `Math.abs` is fine

Comment: And now you guys are into optimisation.  Don't forget that the original goal here was to fix Emily's problem with duplicated output.  Don't try to fix up the part that wasn't broken.  Leave it as 'int k = 0' with a single check and no `Math.abs`, because that's all that's needed to answer her question.